# wordpress registration errors with custom code

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-errors

Anyone know why my following code would be causing a fatal error with the following core wordpress code in users.php line 2610. The code below is in functions.php and when the form is processed the server pops a fatel error for wp-includes/users.php line 2610.

```
// check register form for errors
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
    global $errors;
    if (! is_wp_error($errors)) $errors = new WP_Error();
    if ( empty( $sanitized_user_login )) {
        $errors->add( 'user_login_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The username field is empty' ) );
            return $errors;
    }

    if ( empty( $user_email )) {
        $errors->add( 'user_login_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Email field is empty' ) );
            return $errors;
    }

    if (username_exists( $sanitized_user_login )) {
        $errors->add( 'user_login_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The username you entered is already being used', 'mydomain' ) );
            return $errors;
    }

    if (email_exists($user_email)) {
        $errors->add( 'user_login_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The email address you entered is already being used', 'mydomain' ) );
        //'<strong>ERROR</strong>: A user with that email already exists. <a href="' . wp_lostpassword_url() . '">Recover your password</a>', 'mydomain'
            return $errors;
    }

    include("devteamfiles/inc/bannedwordlist.php");
    if (!checkbannedwordlist($sanitized_user_login )) {
        $errors->add( 'user_login_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: That username can not be used', 'mydomain' ) );
            return $errors;
    }

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['chkagreetos'] )  ) {
        $errors->add( 'tos_aggree_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must agree to site terms of service and disclaimers.', 'mydomain' ) );
            return $errors;
    }
}
```

Users.php line 2610

```
$errors = apply_filters( 'registration_errors', $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email );

    if ( $errors->get_error_code() )
        return $errors;

    $user_pass = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $sanitized_user_login, $user_pass, $user_email );
    if ( ! $user_id || is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'registerfail', sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Couldn&#8217;t register you&hellip; please contact the <a href="mailto:%s">webmaster</a> !' ), get_option( 'admin_email' ) ) );
        return $errors;
    }
```

---

Edited with the code from the answer provided but still popping the fatal error `Fatal error: Call to a member function get_error_code() on a non-object in /wp-includes/user.php on line 2610`

```
// check register form for errors
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
    if (! is_wp_error($errors)) $errors = new WP_Error();

    if (username_exists( $sanitized_user_login )) {
        $errors->add( 'user_login_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: STATEMENT 3', 'mydomain' ) );
            return $errors;
    }

    if (email_exists($user_email)) {
        $errors->add( 'user_login_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>:  STATEMENT 4', 'mydomain' ) );
        //'<strong>ERROR</strong>: A user with that email already exists. <a href="' . wp_lostpassword_url() . '">Recover your password</a>', 'mydomain'
            return $errors;
    }

    include("devteamfiles/inc/bannedwordlist.php");
    if (!checkbannedwordlist($sanitized_user_login )) {
        $errors->add( 'user_login_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: STATEMENT 5', 'mydomain' ) );
            return $errors;
    }

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['chkagreetos'] )  ) {
        $errors->add( 'tos_aggree_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: STATEMENT 6', 'mydomain' ) );
            return $errors;
    }
}
```

Comment: the error is
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_error_code() on a non-object in /wp-includes/user.php on line 2610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in the correct variable $errors but you are overwriting it with the global $errors variable which presumably is not a object.

```
 function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
//global $errors;
//if (! is_wp_error($errors)) $errors = new WP_Error();
if ( empty( $sanitized_user_login )) {
    $errors->add( 'user_login_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The username field is empty' ) );
        return $errors;
}

............
//end with returning $errors!!
return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Let me give it a try, I thought I had tested with the global error commented out but let me try your fix :)

Comment: looking good but now I have two `ERROR: Please enter a username.
ERROR: Please type your e-mail address.
ERROR: Please confirm your not a robot
ERROR: The username field is empty` looks like both core wp and my errors are popping. I should remove my two password and username empty checks and just let core wp do that. Whats the best way to do this without causing another fatal error?

Comment: When I added a statement 1-6 to my code and ran it again, only 1 statement showed up. `    if ( empty( $sanitized_user_login )) {
  $errors->add( 'user_login_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: STATEMENT 1' ) );
   return $errors;
    }` I found that one other statement was coming from a plugin but I can not account for the first two statements that are appearing so they must be from core WP

Comment: Edited code above to show current progress of debugging. Still popping fatal error `Fatal error: Call to a member function get_error_code() on a non-object in /wp-includes/user.php on line 2610`

Comment: I updated above you actually dont need to check is wp error, the errors variable will always be relevant.